# blame VS. reflection

Tags: meaning

**The increase in crime is a sad reflection on our society**

It is a reflection on our society which should make us all sad. The increase in crime makes us sad.

**The increase in crime is, sadly, to be blamed on our society**
It is unfortunate that we have to blame our society. Blaming our society makes us sad.

Although some people might use the second version to mean the same as the first version, technically it doesn't mean that. What you're actually saying is that it's a pity you have to blame society - perhaps you wanted to blame someone else.

*Would you tell me if such explanation would be considered correct?*

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The increase in crime is a sad reflection on our society

Reflection in this sense is ["a thing bringing discredit to someone or something"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reflection). The meaning is something like *"It is sad that our society allows such a thing to happen"*.

Sad can also mean (informally) "pathetically inadequate", as in *"That paper sack is a sad excuse for a briefcase."* I don't think it is used that way in this context, but I think you might see it used that way in similar contexts, so I wanted to mention it.

> The increase in crime is, sadly, to be blamed on our society

Using blame assigns responsibility, where the first sentence doesn't do so quite as directly. The meaning is *"Unfortunately, our society is responsible for the increase in crime*".

"She looked out the window sadly." In this sentence, sadly means she seemed sad when she looked out the window. "Sadly, she looked out the window instead of answering me." In this sentence, sadly is used to mean "regrettably" or "unfortunately".

Another example might be helpful:

*"Your bad behavior reflects poorly on your parents."*

Your behavior makes people think that your parents should have done a better job of raising you. Your behavior isn't completely their fault, but if they had been better parents, maybe your behavior would be better.

*"Your parents are to blame for your bad behavior."*

Your parents are completely responsible for your bad behavior. Maybe you are too young to control your behavior, or their parenting was so terrible that you can't be held responsible for what you do.