# reflect upon somebody as something VS. reflect on somebody

Tags: verbs

> 1. Your bad behavior reflects poorly on your parents.
> 2. Your bad behavior reflects upon me as a parent

Having taken into account [this link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46790/blame-vs-reflection), it is my last question as to this issue. I am wondering if there is any difference between the two semantically.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As they are, the two sentences mean somewhat different things. The first would mean that the person's behavior is an illustration of poor parenting. The second would mean that the person's behavior is mirrored on on the parent. So, the first implies that the bad parenting caused the bad behavior, and the second establishes a relationship between the bad parenting and bad behavior without necessarily giving a cause (though you might say it's implied that the parenting probably caused the behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Original sentences:

> 1. Your bad behavior reflects poorly on your parents.
> 2. Your bad behavior reflects upon me as a parent

To simplify analysis, I will change the sentences.

---

Change the sentences to have the same object (**your parents** vs **me as a parent**):

> 1. Your bad behavior reflects poorly on me.
> 2. Your bad behavior reflects upon me.

---

Change the sentences to have the same quality of "reflects" (**poorly** vs. nothing):

> 1. Your bad behavior reflects on me.
> 2. Your bad behavior reflects upon me.

---

Now, the difference in meaning is obvious: it is the same difference between [**on**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on) and [**upon**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upon).

> upon (preposition) (formal) = on

Therefore, the only differences in the meaning of the two sentences is that the second one is more formal (disregarding the obvious differences regarding the object and the quality of "reflects").

Comment: Technically, the second one doesn't say it makes the parent look bad, just that it reflects on them in some way; the first says it makes them look bad.